# CSS: How to make the padding-right between li even?

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple HTML.

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li>A</li>
     <li>B</li>
     <li>C</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
ul { width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row };
```

I want to make all the `<li>` have the same padding-right so that the sum of widths and padding-lefts of all `<li>` is equal to `<ul>`, like the following:

```
Total ul length: 100px;
(1st li's width + 1st li's padding-left) +
(2nd li's width + 2nd li's padding-left) +
(3rd li's width + 3rd li's padding-left) == 100px;
```

so that the 3 `<li>`'s padding-left are equal.

Can I do this with pure CSS without javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use a table with columns instead? A much simpler solution

Comment: I believe padding-left is not the way to go here. Are you sure you don't want to use `text-align: right;` and `flex-grow: 1;` on the `li`s? Maybe you need to specify what you want to achieve without limiting us to using padding-left.

Comment: @Lee — Because it isn't tabular data

Comment: @Quentin If it's just one row, as detailed above, I really don't think being in a table is going to make any difference. It will provide the easiest correct outcome the poster is looking for (equal width of columns, adding up to the total width of the table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
ul li {
    -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
    flex: 1 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/s9yruoum/)**

Comment: Thank you. I think I need more knowledge about flex box. Thanks for brilliant answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one :

```
ul li{ -webkit-flex: 1 auto; flex: 1 auto; }
ul {display: -webkit-flex; display: flex;}
```

Demo code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/3Lbh98re/)

Comment: Why you made the same solution that i made?

Comment: sir i post answer already but my net was very slow so now only posted @LuisP.A.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to flex, you could also try CSS tables as follows.

Set `display: table-cell` on the `li` elements and add `width: 33.3333%` if you the `li` elements to have the same width.

Note that in this approach, you lose the bullet/maker on the list items, which may be something that you need.

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  text-align: right;
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>Bb</li>
  <li>Ccc</li>
</ul>
```